Positive integral appears negative after applying the convolution theorem
I am Fourier transforming momentum representation of quantum mechanical wave functions to the position representation. In the weak sense (tempered distribution) we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3k \ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} |\mathbf{k}| = -\frac{8\pi}{|\mathbf{r}|^4}.$$
Let $\psi\in\mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right)$ be a Schwartz function. We have that the following momentum integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3k \ |\mathbf{k}| |\psi(\mathbf{k})|^2 \geq 0.$$
By the convolution theorem and the fact that Fourier transform is unitary, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3k \ |\mathbf{k}| |\psi(\mathbf{k})|^2 = -\frac{8\pi}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3r_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3r_1 \frac{\bar{\hat\psi}(\mathbf{r}_1) \hat\psi(\mathbf{r}_2)}{|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|^4},$$
where $\hat\psi(\mathbf{r}) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \psi(\mathbf{k})$.
Here is my question:
How can RHS be non-negative when the biggest contribution to the integral is when $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ are close? Or is the equation wrong?
Thanks!

I think the Fourier transform of $|\mathbf{k}|$ might be wrong.

Maybe it should be $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3k \ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} |\mathbf{k}| = 8\pi \int d^3r'\frac{\delta(\mathbf{r}) - \delta(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|^4}$? Does someone know any literature or table that reveals the 3D Fourier transform of various distributions?

The distribution for $\psi=\frac1{r^4}$ is not defined such that for any $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$, $$\langle \psi, \phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \phi(\vec r)\psi(\vec r),d^3r$$One needs a distribution such as $$\langle \psi, \phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \psi(\vec r)(\phi(\vec r)-\phi(0)1_{B(0,1)}-(\vec r\cdot \nabla \phi)(0)1_{B(0,1)}),d^3r$$

The Fourier transform is wrong. It should be
$$\int d^3k \ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} |\mathbf{k}| = 8\pi \int d^3r'\frac{\delta(\mathbf{r}) - \delta(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|^4}.$$
This can be derived from the fact that Fourier transform of minus Laplacian of distribution is $|\mathbf{k}|^2$ times Fourier transform of distribution together with that
$$\int d^3k \ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|} = 4\pi\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}$$
and it is possible to show
$$\nabla^2\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^2} = 2\int d^3r'\frac{\delta(\mathbf{r}') - \delta(\mathbf{r})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|^4}$$
using the regularization $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^2} = \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^2+\lambda^2}$. Otherwise, it can also be derived using the well-know formula for square root of minus Laplacian.
This implies
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3k \ |\mathbf{k}| |\psi(\mathbf{k})|^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3r_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3r_1 \frac{\left|\hat\psi(\mathbf{r}_1) - \hat\psi(\mathbf{r}_2)\right|^2}{|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|^4}.$$

How did you arrive at the first equality?

@MarkViola, why did you down vote my answer?

I did not down vote your answer.

Okay, sorry. I edited my answer to show how I arrived at the Fourier transform. Hope it was clear enough.
